# Chave Estrangeira no MySql UUID

Tags: mysql, chave-estrangeira, uuid

Olá, estou com um problema, eu criei uma tabela em que a chave primeira é um UUID na v4, porém eu preciso em outra tabela referencia essa chave primaria, dessa vez na segunda tabela como chave estrangeria e tenho o seguinte retorno. Já tentei colocar o type como Sequelize.UUID e mesmo assim não funciona

> ERROR: Referencing column 'processo_id' and referenced column 'id' in foreign key constraint 'modelos_tarefas_ibfk_1' are incompatible.

Estou usando o sequelize para gerenciar as migrations de banco de dados

Primeira Tabela

```
    'use strict';
       module.exports = {
        async up(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    await queryInterface.createTable('modelos_processos', {
      id: {
        type: Sequelize.UUID,
        defaultValue: Sequelize.UUIDV4,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true
      },
      usuario_id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER(5).ZEROFILL,
        references: {
          model:'usuarios',
          key: 'id'
        },
        allowNull: false
      },
      titulo: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING(500),
        allowNull: false
      },
      situacao: {
        type: Sequelize.ENUM('ativo', 'inativo'),
        allowNull: false,
        defaultValue: 'ativo'
      },
      criado: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      },
      alterado: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      }
    },
    {
      charset: 'utf8',
      collate: 'utf8_general_ci'
    });
  },
  async down(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    await queryInterface.dropTable('modelos_processos');
  }
};
```

Tabela em que será usado o id dessa primeira tabela como chave estrangeira

```
    'use strict';
      module.exports = {
        async up(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    await queryInterface.createTable('modelos_tarefas', {
      id: {
        type: Sequelize.UUID,
        defaultValue: Sequelize.UUIDV4,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true
      },
      processo_id: {
        type: Sequelize.CHAR(36),
        allowNull: false,
        references: {
          model: 'modelos_processos',
          key: 'id'
        },
        onDelete: 'cascade',
        onUpdate: 'cascade'
      },
      servico_id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER(5).ZEROFILL,
        allowNull: false,
        references: {
          model: 'Servicos',
          key: 'id'
        },
        onDelete: 'cascade',
        onUpdate: 'cascade'
      },
      titulo: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING(45),
        allowNull: false
      },
      descricao: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING(500),
        allowNull: false
      },
      prioridade: {
        type: Sequelize.ENUM('urgente', 'alta', 'baixa'),
        allowNull: false,
        defaultValue: 'baixa'
      },
      tipo: {
        type: Sequelize.ENUM('atendimento', 'tarefa', 'flowup', 'chamado'),
        allowNull: false
      },
      automacao: {
        type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN,
        allowNull: false
      },
      recorrencia: {
        type: Sequelize.ENUM('diaria', 'dias úteis' ,'semanal', 'mensal', 'bimestral', 'trimestral', 'quadrimestral', 'semestral', 'anual')
      },
      recorrencia_dia: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER(2).ZEROFILL
      },
      prazo: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER(2).ZEROFILL
      },
      criado: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      },
      alterado: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      }
    });
  },
  async down(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    await queryInterface.dropTable('modelos_tarefas');
  }
};
```

Comment: os tipos das colunas devem ser dos mesmos tipos, logo deve ser `uuid`

Comment: Já tentei assim dá o mesmo erro

Comment: já tentou `varchar` para os 2?

Comment: Mais aí o varchar iria peder um pouco a regra já que o UUID são exatamente 36 caracteres, também cheguei a colocar CHAR(36) nos dois e mesmo assim não funcionou

Comment: O uuid eu consigo gerar numa boa, o problema está em usar essa coluna da uuid como chave estrangeira em outra tabela, está dando com os tipos não são compatíveis

Answer (score 0):

Pessoal achei o erro que estava impedindo o relacionamento o grupamento das tabelas que estava tentando colocar a chave estrangeira estavam diferentes, quando eu coloquei para o mesmo usei utf8 utf8_general_ci deu certo, valeu pessoal.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).